# how to avoid a Json array when i'm fetching data

Tags: java, json

i'm fetching Json data in java, and my Json have different structure and not always the same. Example :

```
{"0":{"id"="255",name="example"},"1":{"news_id":"47221","news_infos":{"title":"test","date":"2014-05-14 17:44:02","shared":"47"},"website":"test.it"},"3":{"id"="55885",name="foo"}}
```

This is just an example. What i want to know is how i can skip the second one, we suppose the second one is a JsonArray. 
This is an example of what I'm doing in java ;

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jObj.length() ; i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = jObj.getJSONObject(i); //Suppose that every entry in the Json is an object and not a JsonArray.
                    if (!obj.isNull("titrenews")) {
                        Home home = new Home();
                        Log.i("Infos","Yes");
                        home.setNomC(obj.getString("titrenews"));
                        home.setPhotoAr(photoNews);
                        home.setText(obj.getString("textnews"));
                        home.setNbrSick(obj.getString("sicks"));

                        homeList.add(home);

                    }
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
```

To sum up the problem i have a json data. composed of JsonObject and JsonArray, and what i want is to skip the jsonArray entry and avoid it

so any solutions please !

Comment: Which json library/parser to you use?

Comment: org.json from java i supposed

Comment: your json example is not valid json (check with http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) and does not have any json array. can you pls provide a complete example (complete valid json and complete source code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
for (Object obj : jObj) {
    if (obj instanceof JSONObject){
        //do something
    }
    else if (obj instanceof JSONArray){
      continue;//skip
    }
}
```